# Executing terminal cmd from Python code returns different result in IDE and terminal itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, subprocess

I want to execute `which jupyter` command in Python code in order to receive location of my `jupyter` binary file.

My Python script named `ReportGenerator.py` looks as follow:

```
from subprocess import call

if __name__ == "__main__":
    call(["which", "jupyter"])
```

output is:

> 

But if I navigate to the same folder in terminal and execute code Python script then:

> Kamils-MacBook-Pro-2:project F1sherKK$ python3 ReportGenerator.py 
>   /Users/F1sherKK/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/bin/jupyter

It works... so I made sure my PyCharm IDE is using the same python 3.6.1 as my terminal. I am not using any virtualenv at the moment.

Can somebody explain why this happens?

Comment: Your IDE is using a different environment. You should `Edit Run configurations...` and specify the correct `PATH`.

Comment: Oh so the problem would be `Environment variables:` set to `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`?

Comment: Yes. `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` has nothing to do with it though. You want to make sure that you have correctly configured the IDE environment. Without any mention on how it is configured we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it happens, but here is what I use for a code that runs both from console and from cron:

```
def which(name):
'''
Replace unix 'which' command.
Tested on windows10 and linux mint. Should work on all platforms.
:param name: Requested command name
:type name: str
:return: Full path to command
:rtype: str
'''
for path in os.getenv("PATH").split(os.path.pathsep):
    full_path = path + os.sep + name
    if os.path.exists(full_path) and os.access(full_path, os.X_OK):
        return full_path
raise ValueError('Cant fint command %s')%name
```

EDIT:
On windows, the function will return value on non-executable files.
For writing your own solution for windows see: [descusion](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/577007-need-simple-way-determine-if-file-executable)

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.call()` executes the given command and returns the command's return code (`0` => ok, anything else is an error).

The interactive Python shell (whether embedded in your IDE or not) displays the stdout and stderr streams of the command as well as the return code, but this is only an artifact of the interactive Python shell - as you noticed this will not print anything to stdout if you run the same code as a script.

Here you want to use `subprocess.check_output()` instead, which will return the command's output as a string. Then you need to explicitely print this string to your python's process stdout:

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == "__main__":
    found = subprocess.check_output(["which", "jupyter"])
    print(found)
```

Comment: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['which', 'jupyter']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: @F1sher yes that's what you get when the command failed, __as documented__. You did not specify what the output should be when `which` cannot find `jupyter` so I did not add any error handling code. Now it's your job to handle the case as you see fit.